# Enabling or Disabling Buttons Based on CheckBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I had an I Agree `Checkbox` that when checked or unchecked it used JS to toggle the Disabled setting on a button with `id="submit1"`.  However, I added more buttons and now it needs to toggle all of these buttons rather than just the first, so the `ID` isn't working anymore.

Current Code for `checkbox`:

```
 <input type="checkbox" checked id="agree" name="agree" value="ON" onclick="javascript: if(document.getElementById('agree').checked==true){document.getElementByID('submit1').disabled=false;}else{document.getElementByID('submit1').disabled=true;}">
```

And for `button`:

```
 <button onclick="do_file_form_submit(7);" id="submit1" name="submit1" class="custombutton">Button Number 1</button>
```

So, I have added more `buttons`, so I need 2 things:

1. I need `JS` or `jquery` that will loop through and toggle EACH button when the box is checked rather that just the single button (first button with the ID).

   1. On page load, I also need it to check and see if the box is `checked` and if not, loop through and `disable` all of those buttons.

Thanks so much for any help you can give!!

Craig

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and answers!!!  Shahe's answer was ideal for my situation.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" checked id="agree" name="agree" value="ON">
<button onclick="do_file_form_submit(7);" id="submit1" name="submit1" class="custombutton">Button Number 1</button>
<button onclick="do_file_form_submit(7);" id="submit2" name="submit2" class="custombutton">Button Number 2</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#agree').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('button').attr("disabled", false);    
    } else {
        $('button').attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shahe_masoyan/UpxzB/3/

Comment: Ended up using this one.  Since this is the only place I am using the "Button" tag on the page, this one worked flawlessly.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Check this out [Your working page](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyjose009/UpxzB/6/)

```
   function checkStatus() {
    if ($('#agree_again').is(":checked")) {
        $(".custombutton").attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $(".custombutton").attr('disabled', true);
    }
}

$("#agree_again").change(function () {
    checkStatus();
});
```

You can call this checkStatus function on body load to check whether its checked or not on page load .

Answer (score 0):

asign same classname for all button. 
then use the class name for selector.

```
document.getElementByClassName("custombutton").disabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Hope this resolve your problem

```
$(function(){
//$("#agree").is(":checked")    
    EnableDisableButton(!$("#agree").is(":checked"))
    $("#agree").click(function(){
        EnableDisableButton(!$("#agree").is(":checked"));
    })
    function EnableDisableButton(isEnable){

        $(".custombutton").attr("disabled",isEnable);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="agree" name="agree" value="ON" 
 class="agree_chk" />
<input type="button" class="button" id="button1" value="button1"/>
<input type="button" class="button" id="button1" value="button2"/>
<input type="button" class="button" id="button1" value="button3"/>
<input type="button" class="button" id="button1" value="button4"/>
```

and the javascript is

```
$(document).on('click','#agree',function() {
     $('.button').attr({disabled:!$(this).is(':checked')}) 
});
```

js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5V2Y4/

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<input type="checkbox" checked id="agree" name="agree" value="ON" onclick="change()">
    <input type="button" id="button1">
    <input type="button" id="button2">
    <input type="button" id="button3">

<script>

     $(document).ready(function() {
           change();
        });
    function change() {
        var i = 1;
        for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            var btnid = "button" + i;
            if (document.getElementById("agree").checked) {
                document.getElementById(btnid).disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById(btnid).disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

you can change the limit as the number of buttons changes

Comment: May I know Why I got a down vote. this one actually works fine